# How to get the names of animation clips from a GLB 3D object on A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have created a simple scene on A-FRAME and imported a 3D GLB object which contains 3 animations.

Now I would like to get the names of those animations using pure Javascript so I can use it later on but I can't figure it out how to get them.

Using browser console I was able to locate the names of animations but unable to gather them using JS.

[image: GLB 3D Object Component]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you dig deeper into the components object? 

document.getElementById("GLB3D614").components['animation-mixer'].model.animations

Comment: Thanks @KostasX! I was using that code before on Chrome but I had no result. No I tried on Firefox and works fine...not sure why was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animations reference is kept in a `gltf-model` component property: `model.animations` ([source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/gltf-model.js#L32)). Like KostasX wrote in his comment, you can simply grab the property:

```
// better to check the glft-model, as it is responsible for loading the model
document.getElementById("GLB3D614").components['gltf-model'].model.animations
```

to be sure that the properties are not `undefined`, you should wait until the `model-loaded` event is emitted:

```
// custom component of the entity with the gltf-model
this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', e => {
    console.log(this.el.components['gltf-model'].model.animations
})
```